# TensorFlow Serving System Requirements

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

What would be the minimum system requirements for TensorFlow Serving?  I imagine it would depend on many things such as the size of my model(s) I want to serve.  But are there any kinds of rules of thumb, like tensorflow serving needs at least x amount of memory, or y amount of disk, and z amount of compute?

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** since it seems quite off-topic and unclear.

Answer (score 0):

The model itself will be by far the greatest contributor towards memory/compute requirements. Building with Bazel will require a reasonable amount of memory, but that should be largely mitigated if installing via `apt-get`.

[This](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/87) post makes mention of successfully running tf-serving on an Azure DS1 v1 instance, which is 1 core, 3.5GB RAM.

In summary, you should likely be more concerned with the model's requirements than with tf-serving.